# yarn install is not using most recent version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg-v2

I am working with a selfwritten React component `my-ui` library which is hosted on my own GitLab instance.
In my `package.json` I am including the custom component library `my-ui` like this

```
"my-ui": "git+ssh://git@...org:.../my-ui.git#main"
```

Now, when I push changes to `main` in `my-ui` and I do a `yarn install` in the project where I am using `my-ui` the changes are not reflected. I sometimes have to wait a few days that a `yarn install` actually installs the changes...

I assume this is because `yarn` (or something else?) is caching something?

I tried `rm -rf` the `node_modules` folder, `yarn cache clean` and `yarn install --force` but this does not do the trick. How would I install always the latest version of `my-ui`?

Comment: You have a bunch of typos, e.g. `isnstall` and `--froce`. Make sure you are typing those correctly. Anyways, if you want to update your packages, you can run `yarn upgrade --latest`.

Comment: @four-eyes this looks less like a yarn problem and more like a deployment pipeline issue. Please check whether the changes you push to the main branch are getting pushed to whatever package store you're pushing the build to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for this lays in the `yarn.lock` file.

```
"my-ui@git+ssh://git@git.my-ui.git#main":
  version "1.0.0"
  resolved "git+ssh://git@git....:development/my-ui.git#14f7fcc2199dd2aa261b738c32dacc721c78f0d2"
```

If i remove this line and run a `yarn install` again, it pulls the most recent version. I guess this `14f7fcc2199dd2aa261b738c32dacc721c78f0d2` is referencing the previous installed version.